# no device drivers were found error when installing win7

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I'm trying to install win 7 on dell xps laptop. I burned the win7 on my 16 gb flash with no issues. When installing windows ,"no device drivers were found" error appears. I installed the drivers, and copied to usb, but it is not appearing in "Browse" OPTION, it shows only :

```
c: RECOVERY D: LOCAK DISK E: CD DRIVE X: BOOT
```

So my Question is : Why usbs are not appearing so I can select the drivers to be downloaded?

[image]

Comment: What mode is the HDD in, from the BIOS settings. If it's in RAID mode, Some Windows installations won't be able to see it.

Comment: its is only written "Hard drive"

Comment: fixed HDD : toshiba mk6461GSY

Comment: It is SATA AHCI

Comment: When, exactly does the no device drivers were found appear? Can you show a picture on your question?

Comment: when I click "install windows 7"
https://www.google.ps/search?q=no+device+drivers+were+found+windows+7+installation&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9zOv1uLDTAhWBE5oKHQ9UCEcQ_AUIBygC&biw=1103&bih=587#imgrc=dyK3C1bYpkIxsM:

Comment: is that a screenshot from your machine, or one you found that matches?

Comment: its the same that appeas  on my device

Comment: Don't use 'found' screenshots, they can confuse.

Comment: I'd suggest using a phone or similar to take shots of each stage of the windows 7 install, from when you get the first screen to the error. try to highlight what you are clicking on.

Comment: I tried to show you some screenshots , but I'm not allowed to upload them here because I'm new user

Comment: I think you are going a step too far in your process to get to the screen you've shown. You should only need drivers if you are not being given the option to install to existing drives. I'll see if I can get a guide for you.

Comment: this screen appears after 2 steps only :
1- "install window" button
2- "select a driver to be installed " window 
3- "No device drivers where found" error message

Comment: Follow the steps in my answer. If you have questions, put a comment on the answer.

Comment: @magicandre1984 That would only be true if using USB3. You might want to confirm that BEFORE marking as duplicate.

Comment: @user719952 : can you use a non USB3 port, to check if that is indeed the issue (look for one without USB3 marked or blue in socket).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I believe the issue is that you are going one step too far in the process.

Restart the install, and accept the licence. you should come to this screen :- [image: Win 7 install 1]

Select 'Custom (advanced)' which should bring you here :-

[image]

Now, from here, you need to choose the install disk (in my case, Disk 0) and click next. Windows should now start to install.

You should not click 'load drivers' unless there are no drives to install on.

---

If windows does not get to the screen above, it indicates that the available drives in the machine are faulty. The reason I can say faulty in this case is that Windows Installer carries drivers which allow SATA/AHCI drives to work, and you have stated that the drive is indeed set to AHCI.

in this case, drivers are not your problem! :)

Comment: I guess you did not understand me ,this window does not appear , it will appear after I install drivers , which is my problem. Any way thank you for help and answer .

Comment: I'll update my answer to provide a better explaination of this issue. :)

Comment: thanks for explination , but what happens if I changed SATA/AHCI to SATA/ATA ??

Comment: Nothing, Windows would still be able to handle this without drivers.

Comment: +1, but how can you say that "drivers are not your problem" when this is exactly the case? Win 7 does not have drivers for AHCI mode in the installer, and I, honestly, do not know where to get them at this point of install. There could be another driver issue with USB device as well.

Comment: @Ali Chen I'm sorry, but your assertion that windows does not have AHCI Drivers in the installer is wrong. I've installed countless machines, set to AHCI, and never having to provide additonal drivers. (we had to check, as we were doing upgrades, and older systems were set to ATA). If a SATA drive is set to ATA or AHCI, and is working, Windows 7 installer will detect it.

Comment: @StevenDavison, yep, you are right, if a HDD is initialized/partitioned when BIOS is set to AHCI from the very beginning, then yes, Win 7 will install fine. I believe the problem happens somewhere in the details of MBR format/content. If HDD/MBR is set under legacy settings, but then the mode is changed into AHCI, Win 7 install will fail, I don't know why.